# PowerShell does not iterate MySQL-result linewise - why?

Tags: mysql, loops, powershell, line

I use the following code to make PowerShell print the result of an SQL-SELECT ...

```
[String] $mySQlServerName = "localhost";
[String] $mySQLDatenbankName = "test";
[String] $userName = "root";
[String] $password = "";

$mySqlConnection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection;

$mySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "server=$mySQlServerName;user id=$userName;password=$password;database=$mySQLDatenbankName;pooling=false";

$mySqlConnection.Open();

$mySqlCommand = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand;

$mySqlCommand.Connection = $mySqlConnection;

$mySqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT SourceIPO1, SourceIPO2, SourceIPO3, SourceIPO4, rejections FROM test.malicious_apache;";

write-host $mySqlCommand.CommandText;

$reader = $mySqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

if ($reader -eq $null)
{
    write-host "no result";
}
else
{
    [int] $columnCount = $reader.VisibleFieldCount;
    write-host "$columnCount columns in result ...";

    while ($reader.Read())
    {
        write-output "next row";
        for ($i= 0; $i -lt $reader.VisibleFieldCount; $i++)
        {
            write-output $reader.GetValue($i).ToString()
        }
    }

    $reader.Close();
}

$mySqlConnection.Close();
```

And get the following output ...

```
PS C:\Users\Max> TestSelect.ps1
SELECT SourceIPO1, SourceIPO2, SourceIPO3, SourceIPO4, rejections FROM test.malicious_apache;
5 columns in result ...
```

The SELECT issued with the mysql-client gives about 5,966 lines! Being a PowerShell-newbie I am surprised and confused, this code is used on many websites and seems completely reasonable to me, why don't I get a single output "next row"?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `$reader -eq $null` -> `$null -eq $reader`

Comment: Many many thanks! But: WHY? PowerShell-magic?

Answer (score 2):

When left operand of comparison operator is collection, then result of that operator is not a boolean value, but an array containing all elements satisfies that comparison operator:

```
$a=1..5
$a -ne 3 # return array with four elements 1,2,4,5
$a -gt 3 # return array with two elements 4,5
$a -eq 3 # return array with one element 3
$a -lt 1 # return empty array
```

To evaluate that result, PowerShell have to enumerate collection.

`DbDataReader` implement `IEnumerable`, so it considered as collection by PowerShell. To evaluate `$reader -eq $null` expression, PowerShell have to enumerate `$reader`. As result of that enumeration `$reader` will advance to the end of current result set, so you have no more rows to read. To actually compare collection to `$null`, you have to reverse order of operands of `-eq` operator: `$null -eq $reader`.